# Trocar Entity Framework EDMX por Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

possuo uma aplicação com EF5 utilizando modelagem com EDMX e possuo muito mais experiência e afinidade com Code First. Alguém possui alguma idéia/tutorial de como migrar de EDMX para Code First sem alterar a base de dados e classes de entidades?

Answer (score 3):

Se você puder atualizar para EF6, basta clicar com o botão da direita no projeto, Add -> New Item -> Data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]